# How does SPSS AnswerTree recognize variable type?

Tags: spss

I am working with a dataset having continuous, ordinal and nominal variable in AnswerTree to do CHAID. But some of my ordinal variables have values from 1 to 10 as rank.

eg. Estimated_Income field has values from 1 to 10 where 1 represents lowest income group

But my answer tree reads this variable as continuous variable. Can some one give clarity on how answerTree recognizes each variable?

I am reading input from a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

AnswerTree uses the declared measurement level, assuming that you are are reading a sav file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the measurement level explicitly in the Measurement Level Subdialog box.  See "Setting Measurement Levels" in the help.